# How do I check when rotation has reached a target value?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a code that checks when an object's angle has reached a target value. The problem with the code I have now is that in some cases the code instantly thinks it has reached the target. One case is if starting angle is -90, target angle is 90 and angular velocity is -2. There needs to be something to handle this case, but I can't figure out how.

```
// Object needs to reach a given angle target to advance to the next step in movement path
case MotionEventTypes.NextCondtionTypes.AngleTarget:

    // Check which direction object is rotating
    switch (currentAngularVelocity)
    {
        // Rotating counter-clockwise
        case > 0:
        {
            if(currentAngle >= nextConditionValue)
            {
                // Target reached or passed
                // Set angle to target value to prevent "overshooting"
                currentAngle = nextConditionValue;

                // Load next speed, angle, acceleration, angular velocity and next condition
                LoadNextMotion();
            }

            break;
        }
        // Rotating clockwise
        case < 0:
        {
            if(currentAngle <= nextConditionValue)
            {
                // Target reached or passed
                // Set angle to target value to prevent "overshooting"
                currentAngle = nextConditionValue;

                // Load next speed, angle, acceleration, angular velocity and next condition
                LoadNextMotion();
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    break;
```

EDIT: How the new angle is calculated:

```
public virtual void UpdateMotion()
{
    currentSpeed += currentAcceleration;
    currentAngle += currentAngularVelocity;

    Body.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + MathHelpers.Deg2Vec(currentAngle) * currentSpeed);
    Body.MoveRotation(currentAngle);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? How is the next value calculated ? We need the smallest reproducible sample in order to test your code and give you a correct answer.